# String.replaceAll() with regex gets messed up

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I'm trying to implement the [Swedish "Robbers language"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B6varspr%C3%A5ket) in Java. It's basically just replacing each consonant with itself, followed by a "o", followed by itself again. I thought I had it working with this code

```
str.replaceAll("[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]+", "$0o$0");
```

but it fails when there are two or more subsequent consonants, for example

```
String str = "horse";
```

It should produce `hohororsose`, but instead I get `hohorsorse`. I'm guessing the replacement somehow messes up the matching indexes in the original string. How can I make it work?

Comment: `+` is greedy. You should use `+?` instead.

Comment: I just realized the problem was the pattern, don't know how I could miss that! I just tried using `{1}` and that seemed to work, and so does `+?` - are they effectively the same?

Comment: No. But the quantifier (`{1}`) is actually useless. You can do without it completely.

Comment: `str = str.replaceAll("([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz])", "$1o$1");`

Comment: Ok, totacockok :) If you care to make it an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` means: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

`+?` means: Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)

`{1}` means: Exactly 1 time (meaningless quantifier)

In your case you don't need a quantifier.

You can experiment with regular expressions online at https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2):

```
str.replaceAll("[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]", "$0o$0");
```

**Remove the `+` quantifier** as it will group consonants.

```
// when using a greedy quantifier
horse
h   | o | rs    | e
hoh | o | rsors | e
```

> A plus sign matches one or more of the preceding character, class, or subpattern. For example a+ matches ab and aaab. But unlike a* and
>   a?, the pattern a+ does not match at the beginning of strings that
>   lack an "a" character.
>   https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm